# How to return a reference without requiring Copy trait?

Tags: rust, reference

*The Rust Programming Language* has [an example function that returns the largest element of a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html?highlight=largest#fixing-the-largest-function-with-trait-bounds). It is mentioned that instead of returning the value, it should be possible to return a reference to that value which would allow us to use this function with types that do not implement the `Copy` trait.

The initial function that returns the value looks like this:

```rust
fn largest<T>(list: &[T]) -> T
where
    T: PartialOrd + Copy,
{
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for &item in list {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }
    largest
}
```

I've been trying to modify it for a while now in order to return a pointer to that value instead of the value itself. I'm thinking this could also be implemented using the index, but I was wondering if there was no other way to proceed like in this attempt:

```
fn largest<'a, T: 'a>(list: &'a [T]) -> &'a T
where
    &'a T: PartialOrd,
{
    let mut largest = &list[0];

    for &item in list {
        if item > *largest {
            largest = &item;
        }
    }
    largest
}
```

This code does not compile and the compiler keeps panicking since I'm obviously missing something. In this instance it refuses to apply the binary operation '>', even though I'm "following" so to speak the the pointer that is largest to the value it represents:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `>` cannot be applied to type `T`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:17
  |
8 |         if item > *largest {
  |            ---- ^ -------- T
  |            |
  |            T
  |
help: consider further restricting type parameter `T`
  |
3 |     &'a T: PartialOrd, T: std::cmp::PartialOrd
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'd be grateful if someone had a hint as to what direction I should poke in order to get this approach to work, if possible at all ?

Comment: As mentioned, the compiler says the binary operation '>' cannot be applied to the type 'T'. It suggests further restricting the type parameter T, but how can it be? It's already restricted to types that implement the PartialOrd trait :/

Comment: `&'a T: PartialOrd`. You require that a _reference_ is comparable, then you dereference it to a value before comparing. Why?

Comment: Also, vector ≠ slice.

Comment: @ThéoLouvel panic have specific meaning in Rust, avoid to use it to say something like "the compiler keep not liking my code". https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5872ea2787d8cb62b504a97dbd7d6178 => https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c670e6cd0de2b1bf404711cd1ba65e21

Comment: I dereference it because otherwise I get a warning about mismatched types... If I try if "&item > largest", I end up with a warning that the ref item doesn't live long enough, even though it was declared literally on the previous line

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc853165b1b1099b7e2896b87229468b but I'd write it as https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6740e82878d127ff35bdbe3c913216a2

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks!! I'll be dissecting that to understand where was my mistake. I didn't mean the compiler doesn't like my code, I understand I'm at fault but being new to Rust I'm having a hard time seeing why! Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Editing is explicitly accepted and encouraged as part of site policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). See also [“Too minor” edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326/155423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not being much of a surprise, this turned out to be a silly mistake:
The `item` in the iteration didn't need to be a reference, and `largest` most certainly didn't need to be dereferenced. Here's the fixed version of that code:

```
fn largest<'a, T: 'a>(list: &'a [T]) -> &'a T
where
    &'a T: PartialOrd,
{
    let mut largest = &list[0];

    for item in list {
        if item > largest {
            largest = &item;
        }
    }
    largest
}
```